# flutter saving new variable value

Tags: flutter

i'm working on a flutter project and wondering how to save a new value of a variable. for example if i say `bool X = false;` and in a 'on Tap (){}' function i say X = true; now the new value is true. my problem is that when i restart the application it returns to the old value which is false.

so how i save the new value even if i restarted my app ?

```
bool W1_D1_workout1 = false; 


Container(
    height: 40,width: 40,
    color: Colors.black87,
    child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: (){
             W1_D1_workout1 = true;    
             Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>getCongratsScreen()));
        },
        child: Text('Done',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,color: Colors.white),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: You need to use local db for this case, try [sharedPreference](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

await prefs.setBool('W1_D1_workout1', true); // to Write data to memory

final bool? W1_D1_workout1 = prefs.getBool('W1_D1_workout1'); //to Read data to memory
```

hope this helped ... good luck ❤️.